# Использование Tailwind + Next.js в чем профит?

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, tailwind

В чём преимущество использования технологий подобных Bootstrap или Tailwind в Next.js, если там присутствуют такие замечательные и удобные технологии как Module CSS, Styled Components, библиотеки Material UI, AntDesign и прочие? Вижу появляются требования у заказчиков именно в написании проекта на Tailwind, это что просто дань моде, какой смысл?

Comment: Ни в чём, каждому свои фломастеры подавай) Вообще в последнее время проще самостоятельно пилить под каждый компонент локальные стили, выносить глобальные (кнопочки там, если они тоже не в компоненте, совсем общие стили). Сетки, табы, модалки и т.п уже можно тоже быстро из пакетов наставить, какие нужны и как нужно конкретно под проект. Фреймворки чисто уже для ленивых, которым нужно за 3 секунды собрать и не париться.

Comment: Про Tailwind вообще молчу, просто выперли все стили по классам, и теперь просто какой-то ад в HTML происходит

Comment: спасибо за мнение, я тож что-то не вижу пока преимуществ